# Caliburn Micro Changes from Version 1.1 to 1.5.1?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Do any one knows, what are the changes made in Caliburn Micro 1.1 to 1.5.1, beside adding support to WinRT and Windows Phone 8.

I need this Info, since I am using Caliburn Micro 1.4 in my project and want to update it to 1.5.1?

If there are any major changes, I will go for it.

Is there any change in the naming Conventions?

Comment: Have you looked at their http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/releases/view/97813 release history

Comment: But that didn't gave me much info

Comment: There have been 3 releases (1.2, 1.3 and 1.4) and each contains a changes.txt. Is that not enough? I suspect if you need more info then you need to ask the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from each of the release's changes.txt:

### 1.2

> - Improvements to EventAggregator to improve testability and re-use apart from the full Caliburn.Micro framework.
> - Enabled basic child containers for the SimpleContainer.
> - Some improvements to the nuget install script.
> - Improvements and bug fixes for View/ViewModel name resolution.
> - Fixed some NRE's in the new UriBuilder. NO explicitly throws if it cannot locate the view.
> - Improved logging around searched for Views/ViewModels.
> - Fixed bugs with the WP7 version of Screen.OnViewReady. It now works consistently.
> - Improvements to PropertyChangedBase and BindableCollection to better support serialization.
> - Moved IsInDesign mode out of Bootstrapper and into the Execute class.
> - Added WP7 platform abstractions for vibration and sound effects, including enabling the window manager to play sounds when showing a custom modal dialog.
> - Fixed some bugs in the WindowManager related to bubbling actions.
> - Fixed some issues with the WPF navigation service.
> - Minor refactoring to enable the new "feature packages".

### 1.3

> - Improved serialization of PropertyChangedBase and BindableCollection
> - Enabled the WP7 UriBuilder to actually build a Uri without navigating.
> - Added SetUIThreadMarshaller method to Executor to allow customization of the framework's default thread marshalling behavior.
> - Added optional settings parameters to all window manager apis.
> - Changed FrameAdapter to inject query string parameters into the ViewModel before the conventional databinding takes place.
> - Added a new WinRT project. WinRT now supports Execute, BindableCollection, PropertyChangedBase, ExtensionMethods, EventAggregator and SimpleContainer.
> - Fixed some WPF bugs in Screen
> - Vast improvements and API enhancements to ViewModelLocator and ViewLocator for easier customization of location conventions.
> - Fixed a potential memory leak in coroutines that are cancelled and re-used.
> - Enabled design-time application of convention bindings (preliminary support). To turn this feature on, set the Bind.AtDesignTime attached property to true for your view. If you are using blend's design-time data generation, you can optionally replace ViewLocator.ModifyModelTypeAtDesignTime to perform custom mapping to views. It shouldn't be needed though.
> - Turned ConventionManager.ConfigureSelectedItem into a delegate to allow customizations.
> - Added ConventionManager.ConfigureSelectedItemBinding delegate aimed to allow the inspection of the proposed binding and its customization or rejection.
> - Added Support for WP7 Mango
> - Added Support for Silverlight 5
> - Various improvements made to the NavigationService; improvements to navigation away, tombstoning, etc.
> - Fixed some WPF bugs with TabControl
> - Some improvements to integration between the tombstoning mechanism and the IoC container.
> - The Application property of the Bootstrapper is no longer globally available, to help prevent misuse.
> - Some breaking changes in ConventionManager API related to bug fixes in ItemsControl conventions.
> - Enabled overriding of default services in PhoneContainer
> - Assemblies are now marked as CLSCompliant.
> - Added a new Func to ViewLocator called DeterminePackUriFromType. This function maps a View Type to pack Uri for use in navigation scenarios. Since there is no way to reliable way to determine the Uri from a type, a default implementation is provided which should work for most cases, but can be replaced for other scenarios. This function is used internally by the WP7 UriBuilder.
> - Updated the SL5 build to use the new native UpdateSourceTrigger.
> - Enabled ValidatesOnExceptions when conventional validation is turned on for a binding.
> - Fixed a certain long-standing bug which caused problems when conventions were applied via the Bind.Model property inside of a virtualizing control with container recycling enabled. This may have fixed some other intermitent issues related to the Bind.Model property as well.

### 1.3.1

> - Switching to Semantic Versioning.
> - Added some exception handling for design time bootstrapper operations.
> - Added a custom converter to the MessageBinder so that we can handle converting to DateTime from string.

### 1.4

This includes no changes.txt, so the best I could find was:

> This version includes many bug fixes across all platforms, improvements to nuget support and...the biggest news of all...full support for both WinRT and WP8.